# scale_linetype_manual is not working or shown on legend in R, why?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to have two linotypes (one solid and one dashed) and having it shown on the legend as well (this doesn't show either), I have tried the code below but lines aren't changing, also I have tried adding `scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed"))` before the `scale_colour manual`, and does not do any effect.

```
 data<- data.frame(
          Date=(1:13),
          A=c(1.12,2.78,2.08,1.55,0.67,0.98,1.43,0.42,0.30,0.82,0.51,0.23,0.44),
          B= c(0.10,0.07,0.04,0.05,0.10,0.08,0.12,0.05,0.02,0.11,0.06,0.05,0.11),
          C= c(9.97,6.94,10.87,9.69,12.27,11.27,10.42,10.97,9.15,10.59,11.64,8.86,8.47))
    
    LINES <- c("A" = "solid", "B" = "dashed")
    
    ggplot(data)  + 
      geom_line(aes(Date, A, color = "A")) +
      geom_point(aes(Date, A))+
      geom_line(aes(Date, B*10, color="B"))+
      geom_point(aes(Date, B*10))+
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name= expression(paste("B", "(", mu, "M)"))))+
      scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("A" = "black", "B" = "black"), labels=c(A ~ (mu~M)), (B ~ (mu~M)))+
      scale_linetype_manual(values=LINES)+
      theme_classic()+
      ylab(bquote(A ~ (mu~M)))+
      xlab("")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general advice that you will hear again and again when working with `gggplot2` is that get your data in long format. It makes it really easy to plot the data when it is in long format.

We remove the `C` column which is not required here and use `pivot_longer` to get data in long format, specify `linetype` and `color` as column name and draw line and point plot for them.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  select(-C) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, value, color = name, linetype = name))  + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, 
          name= expression(paste("B", "(", mu, "M)")))) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values= LINES) +
  theme_classic()+
  ylab(bquote(A ~ (mu~M)))+
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have made an adjustment, removing color=name, and adding the scale_color_manual later. so finally used this. <<** library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  select(-C) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, value, linetype = name))  + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name= expression(paste("B", "(", mu, "M)")))) + 
   #scale_linetype_manual(values= LINES) +
  # scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("A" = "black", "B" = "black"))+
  theme_classic()+
  ylab(bquote(A ~ (mu~M)))+
  xlab("") **>>

Comment: However, as I typed on my code,nI was for example modifying values (ie: A*10) to adjust secondary axis units in scale_y_continuous (sec_axis(~./10,), how do you modify the values of A times 10 when using tidyverse? @Ronak

Comment: You can add `...mutate(value = ifelse(name == "A", value * 10, value)) %>%...` ? @Ecg